# Vectorization issue

Tags: machine-learning, octave

Say you have two column vectors vv and ww, each with 7 elements (i.e., they have dimensions 7x1). Consider the following code:

```
z = 0;
for i = 1:7
  z = z + v(i) * w(i)
end
```

A) z = sum (v .* w);

B) z = w' * v;

C) z = v * w;

D) z = w * v;

According to the solutions, answers (A) AND (B)  are the right answers, can someone please help me understand why?

Why is z = v * w' which is similar to answer (B) but only the order of the operation changes, is false? Since we want a vector that by definition only has one column, wouldn't we need a matrix of this size: 1x7 * 7x1 = 1x1 ? So why is z = v' * w false ? It gives the same dimension as answer (B)?

Comment: z = v' * w isn't in option

Comment: The question sounds like you don't have access to MATLAB. Then install OCTAVE instead (which is mostly an open source clone of MATLAB) and try it.

Answer (score 1):

`z = v'*w` is true and is equal to `w'*v`.

They both makes 1*1 matrix, which is a number value in octave.

See this:

```
octave:5> v = rand(7, 1);
octave:6> w = rand(7, 1);
octave:7> v'*w
ans =  1.3110
octave:8> w'*v
ans =  1.3110
octave:9> sum(v.*w)
ans =  1.3110
```

Answer (score 1):

Answers A and B both perform a dot product of the two vectors, which yields the same result as the code provided. Answer A first performs the element-wise product (.*) of the two column vectors, then sums those intermediate values. Answer B performs the same mathematical operation but does so via a dot product (i.e., matrix multiplication).

Answer C is incorrect because it would be performing a matrix multiplication on misaligned matrices (7x1 and 7x1). The same is true for D.

`z = v * w'`, which was not one of the options, is incorrect because it would yield a 7x7 matrix (instead of the 1x1 scalar value desired). The point is that order matters when performing matrix multiplication. `(1xN)X(Nx1) -> (1x1)`, whereas `(Nx1)X(1xN) -> (NxN)`.

`z = v' * w` is actually a correct solution but was simply not provided as one of the options.